# openerp 7.0 create a jasper report that time error dispaly

Tags: openerp-7

I am create jasper report module than after create a report in opener 7.0 than this error display

Report Error

Failed to invoke method execute in class com.nantic.jasperreports.JasperServer: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "gopal"

Answer (score 0):

You should check your .conf, in my case openerp-server.conf, and check if there is something wrong on field db_password. This fields contains your openerp user's password to access your database. In my case my .conf looks like this:
    `[options]
    ; This is the password that allows database operations:
    admin_passwd = myPass
    db_host = false
    db_port = false
    db_user = openerp
    db_password = 1234
    addons_path = my_path/dev_core/addons, my_path/dev_core/my_modules`

At the beginning I didn't set a password to my user openerp so my db_password was false and when I started working with jasper report I had to set a password to it, if it is your case you can set a password like this:

```
su root
su postgres
psql

postgres=# alter user openerp password '1234';
```